# how to pass multiple variables to same parameter when calling postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, function

i have total of 4 records in my table

```
 id |                url                 |        name         | description | last_update
----+------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------
  1 | https://www.postgresqltutorial.com | PostgreSQL Tutorial |             |
  2 | http://www.oreilly.com             | O'Reilly Media      |             |
  3 | https://www.google.com             | Google              |             | 2013-06-01
  4 | http://www.postgresql.org          | PostgreSQL          |             |
```

i have written a function to delete by passing name as a parameter, now i want to pass multiple names but i am facing error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(first_name varchar(255))

RETURNS INTEGER AS

$BODY$

DECLARE emp_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
 SELECT id into emp_id from links e where name = first_name;
 
 DELETE FROM links WHERE id = emp_id;

 return emp_id;

END

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

select * from testing('Google, PostgreSQL');

Error:- no function matches the given name and argument types. you might need to add explicit type casts

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a comma separated list, you can cast your parameter as an array with [string_to_array](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_array_to_string-function.php) function then apply the [any](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-any-operator/) operator. Further there is no reason for pgplsql, this can be written in a single sql statement, then wrapped it into a sql parameter/function. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8ff076f4c9617da22a3b1c2706362f9c))

```
create or replace procedure testing(first_names varchar(255))
language sql 
as $$
   delete from links 
    where name = any(string_to_array(first_names, ',')); 
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass several values, you have to define the function to accept several values. There are two ways:

1. a variadic function:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION testing(VARIADIC first_name text[]) ...
   ```

   This is called like

   ```
   SELECT testing('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
   ```
2. a function that accepts an array as parameter:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION testing(first_name text[]) ...
   ```

   This is called like

   ```
   SELECT testing(ARRAY['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']);
   ```